# Connected components of the difference of convex bodies

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a closed symmetric convex body and consider the difference $D = K \setminus B$ where $B$ is a ball centered at the origin. Is there a bound on the number of connected components of $D$, perhaps in terms of the number of vertices of $K$? It seems for $K$ an ellipsoid you can have at most two components, while for $K$ a regular polytope there can be as many as the number of vertices.

Comment: The answer seems to be independent of the dimension. A regular polygon satisfies your 'number of vertices' answer.

Comment: Agreed, no dependence on dimension. But I'd still like to understand the dependence on the structure of $K$. I think it's not necessarily about the number of vertices, since you can imagine smoothing out a regular polytope a bit without merging any of the components. But it still seems to have something to do with the "corners" defined more broadly somehow.

Comment: If K is not assumed to be closed, the answer is no. Let K be a ball of radius r with a disconnected boundary with countably many components. If B has radius r, D will be the boundary of K.

Comment: Good point Steve, I've clarified that $K$ should be closed in the statement. I think the answer might be that the number of components is no more than the number of boundary points of $K$ with locally maximal curvature. This characterization seems to capture the ellipsoid, regular polyhedron, and smoothed polyhedron cases well. But I have to think more about it to formalize the intuition.

Comment: I suspect you're right. Sadly there appear to be closed symmetric convex bodies with countably many points having locally maximal curvature. On a circle draw a chord subtended by a 90 degree angle. From one endpoint of that chord draw a chord  subtended by a 45 degree angle. Continue around the semicircle, halving the subtending angle at each step. Rotate the resulting spiral around the center of the circle to complete the boundary. Varying the radius of B gives D an increasing number of components.

Comment: Let O be the center of K. In each component G of D, there is a point P such that PO is maximal over the points in G. Each such point P has locally maximal curvature (I think, but can't yet prove). If C is the set of components and M the set of points with maximal curvature |M| >= |C|. When M is finite |M| is an upper bound. Not quite what you wanted, but ...